# Grid/Row view with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would to make a javascript based grid/row view table.

For example, in a page that has like 10 pictures, the user has the ability to either see these picture as grid or to see it as rows. So, when he clicks on the grid icon he see the picture as grid, else he will see it as rows.

Can you give me some tips on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic mechanics for this is very simple. Just toggle a class on list container. In CSS set a set of rules for items that are descendent of that class to change floats or columns or css table properties . Also use that main list class to determine what you want displayed within the items, or how you want them displayed

Once class is removed they go back to block elements and default css

Simple example:

HTML:

```
<ul id="itemList">
    <li>
         <h3 class="title">Item # 1</h3>
        <div class="details">Detals # 1</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.grid li{ float:left; width:30%;margin-right:5px}
.grid .details{display:none}
```

JS:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var txt=$(this).text();
    txt= txt=='Grid view'? 'List view' : 'Grid view';
    $(this).text( txt);
    $('#itemList').toggleClass('grid')
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kzDNe/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer ! by the way can I add some fancy effect ? So, It shows a bit animated.

Comment: sure....I only gave you the ultra simplistic version, from here is only a matter of applying creativity. Also might want to look at plugins like isotope or masonry

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is very valuable !!

Comment: Please, what about if I wanna show the grid first, instead of the list view ? how should I modify the JS part ?

Comment: add the grid class in your original html, and just change the button text logic...switch words "Grid" and "view". Can also change that button text using `if( $('#itemList').hasClass('grid) ){...}`

Comment: I still didn't catch it :( Can you give me the new JS part ?

Comment: By the way can I resize the images to a size of 50x50 for example when clicking on list view ?? So, on grid they'll be in size of 200x200 and in list view 50x50 ??